# Find a specific link in text PHP Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, widget

The task itself is for the Wordpress widget. 
In each post there are links like "https://www.test.com/example/example1/target", and the task is as follows: find the first link in text leading to "https://www.test.com/example/example1/ "and create a variable that takes the value of "target". Is it real to do? If so, how? I will be very grateful for help. Sorry for my English!

UPD:
I've done this (using $company_ticker as a "target")

```
$patt = '~(https://www.test.com/example/example/)(\S+)~';
$company_ticker = '';
if (preg_match($patt, $post_content, $company_ticker)) {
    list( , $url, $company_ticker) = $company_ticker;
    }
```

But I can't get where is the mistake...

Comment: Can you explain it? Where do you want to use it?

Comment: @GufranHasan In Wordpress widget (a new one).   Let's just say, there are 100 posts on the site, in each of them, in the text, there is a link to another site. That is, for example, we have a news blog, in each of the posts there is an advertising link to the site selling computers. Here we have an article about HP, and the blogger put the link in the post, For example "You can buy a HP here www.hpsale.ru/computers/hp And I need to "accustom" the widget to search the product brand through the link.